Checking song url availability AVURLAsset
Please tell me, can I get an error when setting up an AVURLAsset(url: audioURL) session if the url is not available (errors 404, 500, etc.)?
func playTrack(at index: Int) {
        let audioURLString = "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/8c809c18b545d1d745fb90301b4ccbf95f68a4f9?cid=9d2598ec34c2409a9b895a657822c718"
        let encodedAudioURLString = audioURLString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
        
        guard let encodedURLString = encodedAudioURLString, let audioURL = URL(string: encodedURLString) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        if let player = player {
            let asset = AVURLAsset(url: audioURL)
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
            player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                forName: .AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled,
                object: playerItem,
                queue: .main
            ) { [weak self] _ in
                self?.player?.play()
            }
        } else {
            let asset = AVURLAsset(url: audioURL)
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
            player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            setupTimeObserver()
            player?.play()
        }
        currentTrackIndex = index
    }


The URL has nothing to do with the asset. The way to find out whether the resource pointed to by a URL is available is to attempt to fetch it and see what happens.
